# How can i write operation in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, range, operation

Hello everyone i'm doing a macros code with vba, and i would like asking something, how can i write the next operation through vba macro.

Suppose you have a sheet with two columns one called "C" and the other "D" and each cell from this column has the next operation:

```
ws.Range("D1") = 0
ws.Range("D2") = ws.Range(C2)- ws.Range(C1)
ws.Range("D3") = ws.Range(C3)- ws.Range(C2)
... 
ws.Range(Di+1) = ws.Range(Ci+1) -ws.Range(Ci)
```

How can i write in vba syntax an operation like:

```
ws.Range("D:D").FormulaR1C1 = "= R[i+1]C[""C""] - R[i]C[""C""]"
```

Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Your operations have self reference. You can't have D2 = D2 - D1. Are you sure those are the operations you are trying to perform?

Comment: You have reason sir, i mean D2 = C2 -C1 Well is an operation in two columns i will edit my question, thank you for let me see that

Comment: `ws.Range("D2:D3").Formula = "=C2-C1"`?

Comment: You're welcome. I'd suggest an approach to the problem: write down the formula you want in the cell it's supposed to be, then start recording a macro, click on the cell like to modify the formula and then press enter; stop the recording and ultimately see what it has recorded. You can reverse engineer your formula. It's a really good way to learn.

Comment: I think it's more like `ws.range("D2:D3").FormulaR1C1 = "=C[-1]-R[-1]C[-1]"`

Comment: Ye, we noted my mistake at the same time. ^^

Comment: Thank you very much it was very helpful your idea and it's something like you show! in your last comment (i recorded macro) my last question is it works similarly with a range like ws.range("D2:D1000").FormulaR1C1 = "=C[-1]-R[-1]C[-1]"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options. See example of the code below (assuming I understood what you are after correctly)

```
Sub FillCells()

Dim RangeToFill As Range
Dim CurCell As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = ActiveSheet
Set RangeToFill = wks.Range("D2:D8") ''' define the range as required or even better - use named ranges in the so

'''' Option 1  
''' youcan use R1C1 reference style for the whole range - very fast and nice solution
RangeToFill.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]-R[-1]C[1]"

'''' Option 2    
''' or you can use .Offset property of the range object. Note that .Address(0,0) has two zeros for the cell address not to be frozen,
''' i.e. not =$E$2 - $E$1 but =E2-E1
''' This also works but could be slower on big ranges and formula looks pretty ugly to my taste
For Each CurCell In RangeToFill.Cells
    CurCell.Formula = "=" & CurCell.Offset(0, 1).Address(0, 0) & "-" & CurCell.Offset(-1, 1).Address(0, 0)
Next CurCell

End Sub
```

Comment: yea i did it with the first option and i also think is a fast and very nice solution, thank you for your answer